# Powershell Script fails with "Read and Prompt Functionality is not available"

Tags: windows, powershell, ip, ansible, non-interactive

I am running a series of Remove-NetIPAddress and New-NetIPAddress powershell commands. They run fine in interactive mode locally on the machines.

When run through ansible, they fail as they usually prompt the user to confirm the actions.

I have tried -Force, -Confirm:$false to no avail. When I use them, the plays simply hang.

Does anyone know how to get "interactive" powershell commands working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to those cmdlets ATM but if it indeed behaves in such way that you can't prevent prompt you could work around it:

- run command in background job and kill it after some time period (this will not the get the job done always as you said that *sometimes it prompts* but you will at least have a script unblocked).
- implement one of the console automation methods I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765510/82660).